# Using regex to find a character a certain number of times anywhere in a string

Tags: regex, grep

I'm generating all possible permutations of a string *10 characters long* with the *numbers **1, 2, 3***.

I now want to check to see how many of the strings have the number **1 three** times, **2 two** times and **3 five** times.

What is the correct regex for this if I am using egrep?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Using egrep on the command line.

Comment: Can you show your input data and elaborate on your expected output? It's a bit unclear for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [positive lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?=(.*1){3})(?=(.*2){2})(?=(.*3){5})^.{10}$
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/kG6sZ6/3)

However, note that this is not the perfect task to solve with regexes.

---

**EDIT**: Since you said you are using `egrep`, you can use piping instead:

```
echo 3121233133 | egrep '(.*1){3}' | egrep '(.*2){2}'| egrep '(.*3){5}' | egrep '^.{10}$'
```

Comment: Like Olaf and Tomalak said this only solves for 1112233333 rather than all possible permutations.

Comment: Just to make sure I know whats going on.  The (.*) means find the character anywhere?

Comment: @FredLoh, yes. The idea is you want to find it anywhere and not necessary consecutively. For example in 1**23**1**22**1, the bold numbers will be consumed by the `.*` in `(.*1){3}`.

Comment: The regex does not account for strings with more than 3 occurrences of "1", for example.

Comment: @Tomalak, if by *account for* you mean doesn't fail the match - yes. But I'm assuming OP's strings are guaranteed to be 10 characters long, so all `egrep`s can't match at the same time, unless there are exactly 3 ones. If that is not the case, you can easily add another pipe to check that the length is 10.

Comment: They are of length 10 guaranteed.  Solution seems to work from my manual inspection of the output.

Comment: I refer to `(?=(.*1){3})(?=(.*2){2})(?=(.*3){5}).*`, as this matches any string length. BTW, this could be made more efficient by replacing `.*` with `[^1]*` (etc) - this will cause less backtracking internally.

Comment: You can anchor the regex and append `.{10}`, e.g. `^(?=(.*1){3})(?=(.*2){2})(?=(.*3){5}).{10}$`. Cool regex, btw :-)

Comment: @Tomalak, as OP said, the string is guaranteed to be 10 characters long. Even if it wasn't, you can simply replace the final `.*` with `^.{10}$`. Agreed about the negation idea.

Answer (score 1):

This would be faster than regex:

```
input.replace("1", "").length === input.length - 3 &&
input.replace("2", "").length === input.length - 2 &&
input.replace("3", "").length === input.length - 5;
```

Comment: Tomalak what language are you using for the topmost answer?

Comment: @FredLoh Take it as pseudocode, it's just to demonstrate the idea. (It's close to JavaScript, except that JS does not replace *all* occurrences of a substring by default, but I did not want to make the sample more complicated than the idea itself.)

Comment: I'm confused at to what you're doing. You replace the 1's with "" and then cut the length?

Comment: The idea is to remove all occurrences of "1" and after that compare the string length to the original string length - 3. If they match, I have removed exactly 3 occurrences of "1".